# gson object to and from json causing exception

Tags: java, json, gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<Rule, HashSet<Data>>>() {
        }.getType();

String json = gson.toJson(dailyListSave, type);

HashMap<Rule, HashSet<Data>> list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Last line from above code is causing exception

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.

Not sure why? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: dailyListSave is a List<Daily> or an object, for example, Dailais with an attribute List<Daily> ? I think you have the first option but must be the second.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is wrong.

1. When using HashMap with a complex Key class, like in the above
   case Rule class. you need to enable
   enableComplexMapKeySerialization() on a gson object.
2. List item Data class
   is abstract class. When using abstract class to
   serialize/deserialize you need to register your custom type adaptor.

Here code snippet

```
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataJsonAdapter());
        gsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
        gson mGson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Here's the DataJsonAdaptor class implementation

**Important thing is to set concrete class name during serialize and use it during deserialize. Class name is stored in "type"**

```
public class DataJsonAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Data>, JsonDeserializer<Data> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Data src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        result.add("type", new JsonPrimitive(src.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        result.add("properties", context.serialize(src, src.getClass()));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Data deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String type = jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();
        JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("properties");
        try {
                return context.deserialize(element,
                        Class.forName("com.package.name"  + type));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unknown element type: " + type, cnfe);
        }
    }
}
```